# WCF The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Добрый день, у меня возникла проблемы с конфигурированием сервера WCF для передачи больших сообщений, то есть при установки параметров квоты в программе на сообщение:

```
        ValueConfigurationService.ConfigurationBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        ValueConfigurationService.ConfigurationBinding.Name = "ConfigMainEndepoint";
        ValueConfigurationService.ConfigurationBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 6250000;
        ValueConfigurationService.ConfigurationBinding.MaxBufferSize = 6250000;
        ValueConfigurationService.ConfigurationBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 6250000;
        ValueConfigurationService.ConfigurationBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 6250000;
        ValueConfigurationService.ConfigurationBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 6250000;
        ValueConfigurationService.ConfigurationBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384;
```

сервер при запросе выдает сообщение об ошибки,

> {System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The maximum message size
>   quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the
>   quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate
>   binding element. ---> System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException: The
>   maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowMaxReceivedMessageSizeExceeded()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream
>   inputStream)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage
>   httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   TerminateProcess.WCF_Client.IWCFService.GetDataSettingPC(String
>   Parameter, String ParameterRequest)    at
>   TerminateProcess.WCF_Client.ClientRequest.SendRequestGetDataSettingPC(String
>   ParameterType, String ParameterRequest) in f:\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2012\TerminateProcess\TerminateProcess\WCF_Client\ClientRequest.cs:line
>   216}

**Создаться впечатление что он не воспринимает устанавливаемые конфигурации и использует дефолтные, что можно сделать в данной ситуации.**

Comment: Разобрался я с квотой на The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536), теперь ошибка та же но размер другой The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (6250000), почему он дает возвратить сообщение клиенту

Comment: подскажите, а как Вы разобрались с первой проблемой?